# Python - вытащить цифры из картинки

Tags: python, captcha

есть такие картинки:https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVbo8.jpg
как из них "вытащить" цифры?
пробовал с помощью API от сервиса ocr.space, но там не "вытаскиваются" сами цифры

Comment: Есть несколько библиотек, можно начать с этого <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366775/python-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0>

Comment: Я не могу понять, 3 или 8 написано на второй картинке, мне нужна помощь робота 